# ASP.NET MVC 5 External Login not working in Live but working in localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook

In Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
   appId: "xxxxxx",
   appSecret: "xxxxxx");

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "ssssss",
    ClientSecret = "sssss"
});
```

In my localhost both google and facebook external login are working but in my live site facebook is not. In my live site when a user clicks facebook login it will prompt for permission but it will just go back to Login, I think it's returning null

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
    var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
            var viewModel = new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
            {
                Email = loginInfo.Email
            };
            ViewBag.Title = "Register";

            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", viewModel);
    }
}
```

Any idea? My live site is not using ssl.

**Update:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return Content("loginInfo is null");
    }
```

loginInfo is always null for facebook and i've checked the fb id and secret already

after facebook authorization i get redirected to externallgincallback with `error=access_denied` and i see
`loginInfo is null`

[http://example.com/account/externallogincallback?error=access_denied#*=*](http://example.com/account/externallogincallback?error=access_denied#_=_)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a valid SSL Certificate for your website.

Update.

My answer was wrong.
Heero Yuy said:

> I talked with the hosting provider it was their security features that caused the problem. Here is their response: We are blocking all outgoing access to Facebook's network(e.g. graph.facebook.com) due to large number of bad users running Facebook-Bots.

Comment: it's working in my localhost without ssl, i'll try to wait for other solutions as SSL is costly

Comment: Because it's localhost and Facebook knows you are going to test your application.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think there is no other solution because of security concerns

Comment: I talked with the hosting provider it was their security features that caused the problem. Here is their response: `We are blocking all outgoing access to Facebook's network(e.g. graph.facebook.com) due to large number of bad users running Facebook-Bots.`